# Calculated Field to Sum Two Values Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Is there a way to sum up two values from two different sheets.  I have one sheet that looks at full time students as a distinct count of their ID and on another sheet I made a calculated field that takes the contact hours of part time students and divides by 12 (FT course load).  I want to be able to add up these two numbers so that the... SUM(Full Time + (Part Time Contact Hours/12)) = ### and would result in an FTE (full-time equivalent enrollment).

Comment: These values are from 2 separate data sources? If so look at data blending. Or joining, depending on your data source types.

Comment: They are from the same data source.  Its really just a filtering of two types of students.  Full time students I can take their count but for part time, we have to do a small calculation (sum up contact hours and divide by 12) to get a full time equivalent, then we add those two numbers together to get an overall enrollment based on the logic that report is using.

Answer (score 0):

Try a calculations similar to these:

Full Time

```
IF [Type]="FullTime" THEN [StudentId] END
```

Part Time

```
IF [Type]!="FullTime" THEN [Hours] END
```

FTEs

```
COUNTD([Full Time]) + SUM([Part Time])/12
```

Obviously I don't know your data structure, hopefully that gives you enough to go on to start.